# Cannot type in UITextfield in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5

I am using become first Responder for textfield. If i try to tap the becomeFirst responder textfield. Cursor moved to that textfield but i cannot type in that textfield. This issue occurs only in iOS 5 but in iOS 4 it works fine. Please explain me to solve this issue.

```
  if (textField == fnameTxtFld){

        if([fnameTxtFld.text length]>0)
        {
            if ([fnameTxtFld.text length]<= 100) {

                if (![self checkForSpecialChar:fnameTxtFld.text]) {

                    Custom_Alert *alert=[[Custom_Alert alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please check the details entered in First Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];

                    [fnameTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];

                    return NO;

                }
                else
                {
                    [textField resignFirstResponder];
                    fnameTxtImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"birth_date.png"];
                    //    [lnameTxtFld performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
                    [lnameTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];

                    return YES;
                }
            }        
            else {
                Custom_Alert *alert=[[Custom_Alert alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please check the details entered in First Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];

                [fnameTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];

                return NO;

            }

        }
        else {
            [lnameTxtFld becomeFirstResponder];

            return YES;
            // [fnameTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
```

if i am in fnameTxtFld, and i try to tap the lnaneTxtFld cursor moves from fnameTxtFld to lnameTxtFld but i cannot type in that textfield. textwillnot appear in that textfield.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work only Partially. I solved this problem without issue by setting boolean variable in should begin editing. and i will access this variable in didend editing.
Should begin should not called when didendEditing is Called. thanks for ur response..

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is in xcode 4.2 if we use **resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder** in same loop some time we would face this kind of issue, to fix this you may follow below code. this may help you

**resignFirstResponder**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

**becomeFirstResponder**

```
[textfield performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```